# EOS Loki Mail crash an cannot be reopen

Tags: pantheon-mail

I install Loki a week ago and everything was working well. Suddenly I got a message about the crash of the Mail app. I killed it and I wasn't able to launch it. I restart my PC and it's the same now.

My system is up to date.

```
pantheon-mail --version

(pantheon-mail:6732): GLib-WARNING **: g_set_application_name() called multiple times
pantheon-mail 1.0.3
```

What can I do ?

EDIT :

I reinstall it and it crash again. I just launch it from CLI and I got this error.

```
(pantheon-mail:3958): Gdk-ERROR **: The program 'pantheon-mail' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)'.
  (Details: serial 4298 error_code 11 request_code 53 (core protocol) minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
[1]    3958 trace trap (core dumped)  pantheon-mail
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the reason of the bug but I found out how to solve it.

I install `dconf-editor` to be able to manage more easily for editing the dconf system database.
I went throught org->pantheon->mail and disable autoselect (true by default).

And voila !